# Meaning of phrase 'great love of life'

Tags: phrase-meaning

I met [in text](http://www.onestopenglish.com/community/lesson-share/pdf-content/grammar/grammar-the-futures-bright-lesson-plan/156550.article) a phrase:

> A double or a triple line means **a great love of life** and adventure.

and had a discussion about meaning of it.

The first proposed meaning was:

> Biggest love (for a women) of person's life

Another proposed meaning was:

> Love to life. Enjoyment of life.

I bet this latter meaning is correct, but why there is *of* instead *to* or *for*?

Even Google Translate gave me both these translations. Can anybody explain me, what means that phase?

Comment: Google Translate gave you both translations because both translations are possible and plausible, depending on context. What did the rest of the text where this phase appeared say?

Comment: Your text got cut off, but no matter, you should be sure to ***[edit]*** the full context / sentence into your question, don't just leave it as a comment.

Comment: Ok, given that it's talking about *adventure*, then your interpretation of "enjoyment of life [and its adventures]" is more plausible. But if the palmist were talking about the "love line" on someone's hand, and said "a long love line indicates you'll meet the (or a) *great love of your life*", then the other interpretation would have been more plausible.

Comment: You've used all my arguments, that I used in my discussion. It's about a life line, not about a heart (or love) line, so I guess the "enjoyment of life" is better. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about fortune telling.

Comment: It's not about a fortune telling - it's about a meaning of English phrase. Fortune telling is just a context.

Comment: I agree with Michel_T in this case. I had originally voted to close as lacking context, but he has proven to be a very conscientious and collaborative user, and he took feedback in good faith, and added the needed context to his question. So I retracted my close-vote and want the question to stay open. I want to encourage more people to act like Michel. Also, Michel, so you know, we have a sister site who focuses very specifically on non-native speakers trying to learn English, [ELL.se]. Check them out too, you may like them.

Comment: @HotLicks Fortune telling is just incidental to the question.  Call off the CPVPV.  The question is about the idiomatic phrases *love of life*, *love for life*, and *love of my life*

Comment: @Dan Bron Thank you for a link to another site. I'll use it.

Comment: Love to live means a great enjoyment of life.  Every day, you are glad you are alive.

Comment: @ab2 It's clearly about 'Love to live', the question is about love **of** life

Answer (score 0):

I propose that this is meant in the same vein as the following phrase:

...a lust for life...

Your example, "great love of life" is not a common one to my knowledge, but given the context (clairvoyance) its the sort of sentiment that is common to the situation.

As such,"lust for life" is used to describe a person who always tries to get the most joy, happiness, fun and pleasure out of life. Someone who tries to always do the most exciting thing. Someone who tries to avoid negativity and maximise positivity.

I believe "love of life" in your example means the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It is the vivacity of life and thrill therein that would interest you most. Life would present challenges you love to overcome. So to say, that we are gifted with a LIFE is joy enough.

OF is preferred to the exclusion of TO or FOR because life is not something external to you. Moreover, LIFE has many things to offer of which you would bask in the joy of living and beckoning of its adventure.

The line has nothing to do with woman's love, though joy of living permeates with it from birth till death.